# Can you Mirror an Microsoft SQL compact Edition database

Tags: backup, sql-server-compact

We have a PLC inputting summary data into a Microsoft Compact SQlce Edition database. We would like to run queries to on this data, but are unable due to the type of database it is, compact. It, as far as I understand, exposes nothing to the network so we're unable to connect with ODBC connection, or anything of that sort. The company that put it in suggested a database mirror to an existing SQL server database we already have. Which seems plausible except for the extra overhead, which might cause some latency issues. `Is it possible to Do a database mirror with the SQLce as the principle database?` I have seen nothing on-line that makes me think this can be done, in fact I've seen hints that it can't. I am not set on Database mirror we just need a way to get the information off this device.

Comment: SQL Server compact edition does not supports mirroring.

Comment: @Shanky are there any other technologies that would achieve a similar result?

Comment: I am sorry I don't have experience with SQL CE, please wait for others to respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the database file to the desktop and use a tool like SQL Compact Toolbox to query the data
Or you could place a copy of the file on the SQL Server disk drive, and acces it via some SQLCLR code (this will allow you to mix with SQL server data)
Or you can use some synchronization mechanism to transfer the data to SQL server (requires programming/configuration)

Mirroring is not an option at all

Comment: Can you tell me why it won't work? Is it unable to have full logs?

Comment: Can you tell me why it won't work? Is it unable to have full logs?

Comment: It is a completely different database engine, so it cannot exchange logs with SQL Server

Comment: This is a side question, but, how do you learn something like that? How and where can I get more information?

Comment: Sam: Wikipedia - or my blog, for example